# How can I use history.push('/') then once there invoke a function in that component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have 2 seperate components. 1 Component (in a different route) has access to the session (login page), and another component(dashboard). I want to be able to use the functions in login route ('/'), but I only need to do that when a condition is met in another component.

How can I use `history.push('/')` and then once im there, call the functions that are in that component?

This is because i have session data in `'/'` route and I want to use function in that component to get access to that session. But i cant do that in another route. :/

Any alternatives would help too thanks :c

Comment: Wouldn't session data be available in both the components ?

Comment: If you're looking to call functions when a component loads, use the `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook. Outside of that, show us some code along with explanation of what you're trying to accomplish so we're not just guessing.

Comment: does history take a callback? try ```history.push('/', function() {...})

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the https://github.com/reacttraining/history `history`, you can pass a state object as a second paramater to `push()`

e.g. from the github page:

```
// Push a new entry onto the history stack with a query string
// and some state. Location state does not appear in the URL.
history.push('/home?the=query', { some: 'state' })
```